# Changing Line Width with Seaborn distplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I don't find a way to change the line width for one of my sub plots. I have the following which should change the line width of the fitted line, but does not appear to do anything.

```
sns_plot = sns.distplot(distribution, fit_kws=dict(linewidth=2.5))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a distplot, you can pass arguments to the underlying plotting functions with the `{hist, kde, rug, fit}_kws` dictionaries as described in [the official documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html).

If you want to change the line width of a fit you may use `fit_kws`; but by default `distplot` shows a kernel density estimate (KDE) as line. To change the line properties of the kde curve hence use `kde_kws` instead of `fit_kws`:

```
sns_plot = sns.distplot(distribution, kde_kws=dict(linewidth=5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually played with **hist_kws={'rwidth':3} and bins=x** to get more or less same thickness bars as others in my plot.